# Does ArcGIS online Rest APIs provide metadata or OpenAPI specification?

Tags: rest, openapi, arcgis, esri

I am analyzing ArcGIS Online Rest APIs. I observe that APIs does not seem to have support for Open API specification. The API documentation does not provide information on Request body fields for any API for executing POST operation. How do i find fields as as there seems to be no metadata support?

I am referring below document link.

[ArcGIS Online](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/online/administering-arcgis-online-hosted-services.htm)

Comment: you can find a bunch of postman collections here.. https://www.postman.com/search?q=arcgis&scope=public&type=all

Comment: you didn't specify which api you are trying to build a body for.

Comment: It not specific to any one API, i would like to analyze all APIs if possible . Problem is documentation does not show fields, my requirement is to find out all fields of any API i analyze.